# Display show search view as extended by default

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have implemented search view in actionbar. Right now scenario is that, default search icon is visible and when i click on it, it is extending for the text. But i want to show it extended by default when activity is open, don't want to open search icon. For that what should i do? Sorry for my poor English.

Here is my menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

==============================

And in activity, in onCreateOptionMenu() method my code is as follow:

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.videoitem_list, menu);
            MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
            searchView.setFocusable(false);

            ((EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            ((EditText)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should clear the search, remove the focus and then call:

searchView.setIconified(true);

Comment: I used this line of code and I can see the expanded search view but clear text icon is gone. How can i get that icon for clear text?

Comment: put this line of code and can see the extended search view but i face the problem. I am not visible the setting icon from the right corner.

Answer (score 0):

**try this one in onCreateOptionMenu**

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the property `android:iconifiedByDefault="false"` on XML or set programatically `setIconifiedByDefault(false)`.It will expand `searchView`.

you may find more details here.[public void setIconifiedByDefault (boolean iconified)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setIconifiedByDefault%28boolean%29)

Comment: I used this line of code and I can see the expanded search view but clear text icon is gone. How can i get that icon for clear text?

Comment: @Ravi, Initially the `SearchView`  will be empty so, cross icon for clear text will not be visible. But whenever you start typing in it that cross button for clear text will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using appcompat use

```
MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(mSearchMenuItem);
```